# Creating a multi-level association rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm trying to develop a job board style web app.

In my current model:

```
entrepreneur has_many :opportunities
opportunity belongs_to :entrepreneur
```

So basically the opportunities model is the table where the user(Entrepreneur) creates jobs positions available at his/her company. I am thinking to add another level of association called applications where for every opportunity you would have multiple candidates applying.

So the proposed model would be

```
entrepreneur has_many :opportunities
opportunity has_many :applications
```

I would appreciate any feedback of whether or not this is the suitable schema for my proposed app.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic makes sense. You may want to consider changing the model name from Entrepreneur to Company, since it's really the company that has the jobs available. But assuming you're sticking to Entrepreneur, in the end, you'll have:

```
entrepreneur has_many :opportunities

opportunity belongs_to :entrepreneur
opportunity has_many :applications
```

Which is exactly what you proposed!